# Adjust horizontal position of plot title using margin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to use vjust within element_text, to adjust the vertical position of my plot to no avail. So I'm using margins instead.

Here is a simplified example:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()+ ggtitle("Test Title ...")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = -20, l = 0)))
```

This brings the title down as I want, but now it's aligned all the way to the left; I want it **centered**. I've tried adjusting various parameters to no avail. Note that vjust is NOT an option, it works in this data example, but not with my more complex plot. I need a solution that uses margin within the call `plot.title=element_text()!`

Comment: Are you able to use hjust with the margin adjustment? i.e.`theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, b = -20), hjust = 0.5))`

Comment: Thank you! I tried that before but I set the r  and l parameters to 0 and it didn't accept it. I guess since hjust corresponds with r and l, I should have left that out in my call!

Comment: @NewBee `element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = -20, l = 0), hjust = 0.5)` also works. Perhaps your parentheses were off and you defined `hjust` within `margin`.